# Android NativeActivity receiving android/os/Handler

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

My goal is to receive a message via `WebMessagePort.setWebMessageCallback( 0, MyHandler )` in JNI land.

Like a similar mechanism to running code on the UI thread, I am hoping to use `ALooper_addFd` - except - that I don't see any clear mechanism to get the raw event that is called back on the looper, even when I entangle the ALooper and the thread's current looper (By creating a Looper object first, then calling `ALooper_forThread()`.

I am able to create a handler that is attached to the Looper I've created in this way, but, I do not seem to be able to have any way to receive the raw `Handler` object in my NativeActivity C code.

It seems strange that you can entangle ALooper's with Loopers, for instance so you can run codeon the UI thread, but that they remain eerily distant from one another.

Is there some mechanism to getting the Java side of the Looper to notify the C code of an event's execution, preferably through the file IO pipes or other activity events? I.e. via the NativeActivity's callbacks?

Comment: For anyone else wondering - you can sort of get a little closer by calling `Looper.loop()` on your thread with the ALooper.    Still not quite there but much closer.

Comment: Why dont you want to use jni interface?

Comment: Because the JNI ALooper_* interface can't get messages from Java handlers.  (unless I'm missing something)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by manually iterating through the messages, by calling `next` on the looper's `MessageQueue`.  That way you receive the Java objects and callback yourself that would ordinarily be executed.

From there you can extract the payload and do what you wish without calling a null callback, which would cause everything to break.

Interpreting the MessagePayload is tricker. In some versions of Android, you can access the b for String and c for byte[] fields of MessagePayload and for others yet, you have to back out one more step and you can access the byte array for the MessagePayload Object.

I have an example of this here:
https://github.com/cnlohr/rawdrawandroid/blob/a77293aadb95f59cb3c2e8987bc976c06bee5a65/test.c#L317-L418

```c
    jclass LooperClass = env->FindClass(envptr, "android/os/Looper");
    jmethodID myLooperMethod = env->GetStaticMethodID(envptr, LooperClass, "myLooper", "()Landroid/os/Looper;");
    jobject thisLooper = env->CallStaticObjectMethod( envptr, LooperClass, myLooperMethod );
    if( !thisLooper )
    {
        jmethodID prepareMethod = env->GetStaticMethodID(envptr, LooperClass, "prepare", "()V");
        env->CallStaticVoidMethod( envptr, LooperClass, prepareMethod );
        thisLooper = env->CallStaticObjectMethod( envptr, LooperClass, myLooperMethod );
        g_attachLooper = env->NewGlobalRef(envptr, thisLooper);
    }

    jmethodID getQueueMethod = env->GetMethodID( envptr, LooperClass, "getQueue", "()Landroid/os/MessageQueue;" );
    jobject   lque = env->CallObjectMethod( envptr, g_attachLooper, getQueueMethod );

    jclass MessageQueueClass = env->FindClass(envptr, "android/os/MessageQueue");
    jmethodID nextMethod = env->GetMethodID( envptr, MessageQueueClass, "next", "()Landroid/os/Message;" );
    
    jclass MessageClass = env->FindClass(envptr, "android/os/Message");
    jfieldID objid = env->GetFieldID( envptr, MessageClass, "obj", "Ljava/lang/Object;" );
    jclass PairClass = env->FindClass(envptr, "android/util/Pair");
    jfieldID pairfirst  = env->GetFieldID( envptr, PairClass, "first", "Ljava/lang/Object;" );

    while(1)
    {
        // Instead of using Looper::loop(), we just call next on the looper object.
        jobject msg = env->CallObjectMethod( envptr, lque, nextMethod );
        jobject innerObj = env->GetObjectField( envptr, msg, objid );
        const char * name;
        jstring strObj;
        jclass innerClass;
        
        // Check Object Type
        {
            innerClass = env->GetObjectClass( envptr, innerObj );
            jmethodID mid = env->GetMethodID( envptr, innerClass, "getClass", "()Ljava/lang/Class;");
            jobject clsObj = env->CallObjectMethod( envptr, innerObj, mid );
            jclass clazzz = env->GetObjectClass( envptr, clsObj );
            mid = env->GetMethodID(envptr, clazzz, "getName", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
            strObj = (jstring)env->CallObjectMethod( envptr, clsObj, mid);
            name = env->GetStringUTFChars( envptr, strObj, 0);
            env->DeleteLocalRef( envptr, clsObj );
            env->DeleteLocalRef( envptr, clazzz );
        }

        if( strcmp( name, "z5" ) == 0 )
        {
            // Special, Some Androids (notably Meta Quest) use a different private message type.
            jfieldID mstrf  = env->GetFieldID( envptr, innerClass, "a", "[B" );
            jbyteArray jba = (jstring)env->GetObjectField(envptr, innerObj, mstrf );
            int len = env->GetArrayLength( envptr, jba );
            jboolean isCopy = 0;
            jbyte * bufferPtr = env->GetByteArrayElements(envptr, jba, &isCopy);

            if( len >= 6 )
            {
                const char *descr = (const char*)bufferPtr + 6;
                char tcpy[len-5];
                memcpy( tcpy, descr, len-6 );
                tcpy[len-6] = 0;
                snprintf( fromJSBuffer, sizeof( fromJSBuffer)-1, "WebMessage: %s\n", tcpy );

                env->DeleteLocalRef( envptr, jba );
            }
        }
        else
        {
            jobject MessagePayload = env->GetObjectField( envptr, innerObj, pairfirst );
            // MessagePayload is a org.chromium.content_public.browser.MessagePayload

            jclass mpclass = env->GetObjectClass( envptr, MessagePayload );

            // Get field "b" which is the web message payload.
            // If you are using binary sockets, it will be in `c` and be a byte array.
            jfieldID mstrf  = env->GetFieldID( envptr, mpclass, "b", "Ljava/lang/String;" );
            jstring strObjDescr = (jstring)env->GetObjectField(envptr, MessagePayload, mstrf );

            const char *descr = env->GetStringUTFChars( envptr, strObjDescr, 0);
            snprintf( fromJSBuffer, sizeof( fromJSBuffer)-1, "WebMessage: %s\n", descr );

            env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(envptr, strObjDescr, descr);
            env->DeleteLocalRef( envptr, strObjDescr );
            env->DeleteLocalRef( envptr, MessagePayload );
            env->DeleteLocalRef( envptr, mpclass );
        }
        env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(envptr, strObj, name);
        env->DeleteLocalRef( envptr, strObj );
        env->DeleteLocalRef( envptr, msg );
        env->DeleteLocalRef( envptr, innerObj );
        env->DeleteLocalRef( envptr, innerClass );
    }
}
```